# Regex multiple characters but without specific string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have lines which consist of:

- optional: "no ",
- optional: two non whitespace characters,
- several non whitespace characters.

I want to capture string from each line which consist of:

- optional: two non whitespace characters (but not "no " part),
- several non whitespace characters.

Example lines:

```
ab123
ab 123
no abc123
no ab 123
```

I want to capture:

```
ab123
ab 123
abc123
ab 123
```

My regexp (works only for examples without "no ").

```
^
  (?! no \s) # not "no "
  ( # match it
    (?: \S{1,2} \s )? # optional: 1-2 non whitespace characters and one space, BUT NOT GET "no " (it doesn't works)
    \S+ # non whitespace characters
  )
$
```

Example online (4 unit tests): https://regex101.com/r/70soe2/1

Maybe should I use negative look ahead `(?! no \\s)` or negative look behind `(?<! no \\s)` in some way? But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Use a capturing approach, `^(?:no\s)?((?:\S{1,2}\s)?\S+)$`, see https://regex101.com/r/XcntiK/1. Or , use `\K`, `(?:no \s \K)?`. see https://regex101.com/r/70soe2/2

Comment: I have much more complicated regexp and I have isolated my problem. My application is "regexp based". I tried learn to negative look behind (https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) but I can't apply this to this case. By the way applying this will be educational goal for me.

Comment: Thanks, `(?:no\s)?` it works! Without negative look ahead/behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot actually rely on lookarounds here, you need to consume the optional `no` + whitespace part of the string.

It is best to use a **non-capturing optional group** at the start:

```
^
  (?: no \s)? # not "no "
  ( # capture it
    (?: \S{1,2} \s )? # optional: 1-2 non whitespace characters and one space, BUT NOT GET "no " (it doesn't works)
    \S+ # non whitespace characters
  )
$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XcntiK/2)

The value you need is inside Group 1.

If your regex engine supports `\K` construct, you may use this instead:

```
^
  (?:no \s \K)? # not "no "
  ( # match it
    (?: \S{1,2} \s )? # optional: 1-2 non whitespace characters and one space, BUT NOT GET "no " (it doesn't works)
    \S+ # non whitespace characters
  )
$
```

The `\K` in `(?:no \s \K)?`  will omit the consumed string part from the match value, and you will get the expected result as a whole match value.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/70soe2/2)