# Regexp to extract "numbers" with optional prefix or at beginning of line

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I want to extract "numbers" (it can be package number, invoice number etc.) from lines. It's just non-whitespace characters (e.g.: `123`, `ABC`, `Abc`, `ABC123`, `ABC-123`, `X-ABC/123/456` - simply `\S+` regexp).

I have lines that can contain "numbers". There are two possible cases:

1. At the beginning of line (first string of non-whitespace charactes).
2. In the middle of line, but marked with prefix `Number:` .

Example lines:

```
ABC123 bla bla
Number: ABC123 bla bla
Some words 123 Number: ABC123 bla bla
```

From those each example line I want to extract "number": `ABC123`.

---

I know how to write regexp for second case (example 2 and 3 lines): `(?:Number: )(\S+)` (non-captured group with prefix `Number:`  and captured group with non-whitespace charactes).

[image: only first case]

**But what with first case?**

What i tried:

1. Prefix can be optional: `(?:Number: )?(\S+)`

I get many matches, but it's not a problem because I can get first match in each line in my code.

But the problem is in match 7: I get word `Some` instead of number `ABC123`.

[image: first]

2. Use start line. So there are two alternatives: start line and "number" OR prefix and "number": `(?:^(\S+))|(?:(?:Number: )(\S+))`.

But the problem is the same, I get word `Some`. And this is worse because I get `Number:`

[image: second]

3. I can add not `Number:` at start of line to eliminate second problem from previous step: `(?:^(?!Number:)(\S+))|(?:(?:Number: )(\S+))`.

But there is still problem with getting random word (`Some`) at beginning of line even when prefix `Number:` exists with "number" in the middle of line.

[image: third]

---

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/G9UFak/1

Question a bit similar to: [Regex multiple characters but without specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63831555/regex-multiple-characters-but-without-specific-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?:.*Number:\s*|^)(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zinfY1/1).

*Details*

- `(?:.*Number:\s*|^)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `.*Number:\s*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, `Number:` and zero or more whitespaces (if you need to stay on the line, replace `\s` with `[^\S\r\n]` or `\h` / `[\p{Zs}\t]` if supported)
  - `|` - or
  - `^` - start of a line (with `m` option in PCR0-like engines)
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: any one or more non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use:

```
^(?:.*?Number: )?(\S+)
```

Where both leading text and "Number:" is optional. See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hSWyrZ/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `.*?` - 0+ characters (lazy) other than newline.
  - `Number:`  - Literally "Number: ".
  - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional.
- `(\S+)` - Your syntax to capture 1+ non-whitespace characters. I'd say maybe you want to use `(\w+)` instead, or even something more precise.